# Weapons for four-armed humanoids?

Tags: biology, warfare

What are the best and most likely weapons used by a race of four armed human-like creatures?

Comment: Questions asking "What is the best weapon for x?" are often closed as too broad. The answer to "What is the best weapon for a human?" is dependent upon the time period, expected use case, cost, legality, fashion, existing logistical infrastructure, and intended enemy. The [list of human weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_weapons) on wikipedia is so long that it is composed entirely of other lists. Without providing sufficient context this question is extremely broad.

Comment: Hi, Tamotamo77, welcome to Worldbuilding Stack Exchange. As @sphennings said, this is a really, really broad question. There are some things you could do to fix it and maybe get it reopened: 1) Specify some more details about the humanoids, including their biology and other characteristics. 2) Specify the technological level of the species, as well as the technological level of any other race they might fight. 3) Specify what you mean by best (lightest? deadliest? most efficient?). Also, feel free to take the [tour] and check out the [help] for more information about the site.

Comment: Consider the following: Humans have created bazilions of different kinds of weapons over our history and we still use thousands of different weapons today.  Which one is best depends on the circumstance, not on the number of arms we have.  Considering basically all hand-held weapons fall into the categories of club, stab, slash, whip, twang, and bang I can't see that your aliens would do anything differently than we.  (But they could do it twice as often....)

Comment: A [lightsaber](http://www.starwars.com/databank/general-grievous)?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the parallel question: best and most likely weapon used by a human.

Technological level is not stated so humans will be considered over the entire time span of their existence.  For much of this time there was minimal technology and so the most likely weapon will be one made from natural materials.

Assuming an arm, brain and eye that works like a human: one great ability of the human is to judge distances and trajectories and one huge advantage humans have over animals is the ability to throw things.  Projectile weapons are better than weapons that require close quarters because they decrease your chance of being hurt by your adversary, especially an adversary that does not have projectile weapons, like an animal.

Most likely projectile weapon is the one most readily available.

So
1: Low tech most likely.
2:  Projectile weapon is best.
3:  Low tech projectile weapon which is most available is most likely.

**Your creature's best and most likely weapon is a rock.**

No joke.  Imagine a pro baseball pitcher with a pile of good rocks facing off against a pack of guys with swords starting 100 yards away.  If the sword guys were well trained, confident and did not slow down, with luck a couple might reach him.  Or maybe not.  Now imagine the pitcher has 4 throwing arms.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are obviously too broad and opinion based. It sets a bad example, especially since you're a high rep user.

Comment: About the four-armed pitcher though... When throwing a rock, javelin or grenade to any useful distance, one needs to deploy whole body.
Throwing with several arms in rapid sequence would not neccessarily give better results.